# three button using one image picker, the image is not update

Tags: swift, xcode

I start learning Swift and try to fulfill using one image picker change button image when users trigger one of three buttons.

I watch online resource and understand how to use one image picker for changing one button image

But now I have three buttons, and each of them should have the ability to use image picker and change their own button image.

My solution for this is every time when the button is clicked and image picker is called, I set the UIImage outside the function equal to the info image

At meanwhile, knowing that image picker has triggered because the button was pushed down, I put a line for set-button-image with that UIImage in the button (IBAction function).

Below is my source code. Somehow the way I wrote will not update the button's image correctly.

Let me know if any information is missing or confused. Any advice or knowledge will be helpful, thanks.

[sourceCode1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ihHV.png)

[sourceCode2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QJEm.png)

[main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZSro.png)

[after clicking the add button the library shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqs8I.png)

[after select image, the button image shows all white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAgxm.png)

[after clicking the white part, the image somehow shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs5aA.png)

[If I click another button, the button change like the first button???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyRRh.png)

Comment: how you want to update button  image ??

Comment: Can you please send me your naviagationController delegate method code ?

Comment: I put three buttons on the storyboard, I try to put an image that I select from image picker on the button, the size should fit the button size.

Comment: I did not write any code for the navigation controller delegate

Comment: Welcome Ping. It would be easier you to edit your question and copy/paste the errors you get (text better than linked pictures). If you need you can see the help to format at stackoverflow.com/editing-help